# How to save name for user in all views in ASP MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a simple chat application, where user chooses his name in homepage and then, he can be sending messages in chat page. I dont know how to remember user's name without using model. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store it in `Session`. Assign it in a controller like `Session["UserName"] = "John Doe";` Then, in the View you can access `@Session["UserName"]` directly, or pass it on via a ViewModel.

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Set UserName to AuthCookie;

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(UserName, false);
```

In Global.asax AuthenticateRequest method, you can make a public ticket string variable and decrypt Authentication Cookie.

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket;
public static string tempTicket = "";

protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest() {

        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            if (ticket != null)
            {
                tempTicket = ticket.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                tempTicket = "";
            } 
        }

    }
```

And you can call the tempTicket which defined in Global.asax where ever you want like this;

```
 string globalTicketVariable =  MvcApplication.tempTicket;
```

**Update 1**: Datatypes are missing, I just declared them. And here is a sample to use it.

```
public ActionResult Login(){
            if (globalTicketVariable != null && globalTicketVariable != "")
            {
                    DataContext Context = new DataContext();
                    User TempUser = Context.User.Where(x => x.UserID == (int)globalTicketVariable).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (TempUser != null)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Success", "SuccessPage");
                    }
            }
            return View();
}
```

Hope Helps.